# How to authenticate Admin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

Hello I am creating a node.js application using express, mongodb, and mongoose. I am trying to create an admin panel and creating a log in route so only admins can access it. I am using passport to authenticate normal users but I am a bit confused on how I should handle Admins. Should I make a completely seperate Admin schema? Can I use my account already created in Users to allow admin access? I'm new to all of these and don't know how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: access would be based upon a user level, rbac or whatnot.. passport only handles the login check so it's upto your app to decide what the users role is and when checking via the session or jwt you would store the role.. or just lookup the user again by the id.

Comment: Probably the simplest thing to do is use one Auth route for users, but store the Admin property as a bit on the User model. Something like: `isAdmin: { type: boolean, default: false }` in your schema.

Comment: @JSONaLeo thanks this is actually what I was looking for! My question to you is once I update the user model with isAdmin, how would i go about passing this to existing users??

Comment: If you already have a bunch of existing users, you could either do an updateMany, like `await User.updateMany({}, { $set: { isAdmin: false} });` type query or create the field as optional, and only reveal the Admin panel to those users who even have the isAdmin field as a property, and where it is set to `true`. Once it's created with a default though, all new Users will get the field added as `false` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: You could also create an Admin Model that associates with a User. You would have to be a User to have one but by having an entry in the Admin Collection a User would be able to have Admin privileges (plus any additional Admin specific attributes you want your administrators to have)

Comment: or you could create a Permissions model that all users have and 'Admin' would be among those possible permissions. May be a better choice if you want to manage various tiers of access. Maybe the real point here though is, there are a really a lot of options for this type of thing

Comment: @JSONaLeo thanks for your help! Association is something I had not previously thought of either. Currently I just went in to mlab and added an isAdmin key set to true directly on my user data. I'm going to try to code a simple middleware that checks to see if req.user.isadmin is true then renders my admin page. Hopefully it works